# Having trouble with Polymer repeat

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am very new to Polymer (and to Dart) and I suspect I'm missing something obvious here. In my app I have code that iterates over a list of objects and presents the items as LI elements in a UL. The list is not getting rendered correctly.

After simplifying what I have, here is the Dart code for my custom element:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('users-element')
class UsersElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable List users = toObservable(['Mike', 'Anne', 'Kim']);
  UsersElement.created() : super.created() {}
}
```

And here is the relevant html code:

```
<polymer-element name="users-element">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <li repeat="{{user in users}}">
        {{user}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="users_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your Dart code looks fine. The problem is the way you are using the `repeat`.
You cannot attach the `repeat` to the `<li>` directly. Instead, you need to
wrap the `<li>` in a `<template>` tag, and attach the `repeat` to that. 
This should work:

```
<polymer-element name="users-element">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{user in users}}">
        <li>
          {{user}}
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="users_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```